# Integral of vector with respect to another vector

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

It's been some time since I was fluent in multivariable calculus and I am trying to work through some basic concepts.

Say I have some function which maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

We can take, for example, $n = 4$, and the function $Q(x) = (2x_1, 3x_2 + 1, 4x_3 + 5, 10x_4)$

How do I integrate this with respect to the vector $x$?

Comment: What kind of integral? Component wise? Line integral? Volume integral?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as an "integral of a vector with respect to another vector".

However, I can imagine the following setup:

There is a celestial body $B$ far out in the sky, and it produces a certain gravitational force on a mass point $m$ at the origin. This force is the integral over $B$ of the "infinitesimal" force contributions coming from the atoms of $B$. Assuming that we have a uniform mass density $\rho$ on $B$ the net resulting force ${\bf F}$ on $m$ is given by the integral 
$${\bf F}=\gamma \>m\int_B{1\over |{\bf x}|^2}{{\bf x}\over|{\bf x}|}\>\rho\>{\rm d}({\bf x})\ ,$$
where $\gamma$ denotes the gravitational constant. We see here a vector-valued function being integrated over a threedimensional domain $B$.

Answer (score 0):

For a function $Q:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$, write
$$Q(x)=(Q_1(x),\ldots,Q_n(x)),$$
where the $Q_i$'s are functions $Q_i:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$. Then, the integral of $Q$ (if it exists) is a vector in $\Bbb R^n$ defined by the equation
$$\int_{\Bbb R^n}Q\,dx:=\left(\int_{\Bbb R^n}Q_1\,dx,\ldots,\int_{\Bbb R^n}Q_n\,dx\right),$$
where each $\int_{\Bbb R^n}Q_i\,dx$ is the usual multiple integral
$$\int_{\Bbb R^n}Q_i\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\cdots\int_{-\infty}^\infty Q_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)dx_1\ldots dx_n.$$